# Foursquare: Venue count of users being at the same venue for iOS

Tags: swift, foursquare

I’m trying to use Foursquare online API, which I need to retrieve the property of the count of users are at the current venue. 
However, Foursquare’s documentation related to Venue [here](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/herenow) draws a confusions for me.

First, *is it possible that when I do a HTTP request, I do the request with userless authentication, i.e. parsing the parameters with just the app's `client_id` and `client_secret*?

Any quick explanation, (greater appreciation for those who even provide some code examples) regarding this confusion will be appreciated so much!

Comment: You can do the request with userless authentication. In that case, API return only ‘count’ param. API does not return a list of friends and friends-of-friends.

Comment: @KosukeOgawa, it's actually not correct, as I even tested the HTTP request through this API testing tool called apigee. It said it need a user authentication (Check out this link here)- [https://apigee.com/console/foursquare?req=%7B%22resource%22%3A%22getvenuedetails%22%2C%22params%22%3A%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%22v%22%3A%2220131016%22%7D%2C%22template%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22headers%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22body%22%3A%7B%22attachmentFormat%22%3A%22mime%22%2C%22attachmentContentDisposition%22%3A%22form-data%22%7D%7D%2C%22verb%22%3A%22get%22%7D]

Comment: You're right. User Authentication is required. I am mentioning "Userless Server Integrations". https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth#authentication

Answer (score 0):

The `herenow` endpoint requires an acting user. See the [Foursquare guide on authentication](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth) for more detail about how to get an authentication token to make an API request as an acting user.

> Access tokens allow apps to make requests to Foursquare on the behalf
>   of a user. Each access token is unique to the user and consumer key.